# Is there an algebraic way to find the greatest integer value of a function raised to an integer?

Tags: functions

For example, what is the greatest integer value of \begin{equation}3^{{-x}{\left({x}-3 \right)}}\end{equation}?

Comment: How far have you gotten with this?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: I can find that the function gets its maximum value at x=3/2 as 3^3/2. However, how can I be sure that this value is less than 12 without graphing?

Comment: Isn't that its minimum value? Or did you miss out a minus sign?

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. I have corrected the sign.

Comment: So basically, you are asking how to check that $11\leq 3^{9/4}<12$? To see this, just raise both sides of the inequality to fourth power. Well, with $12$, you can first divide by three to ease the computation. Then you only need to  check that $3^5<4^4$.

Comment: I don't think I understand the problem.  First of all, at $x=\frac32$, isn't the function value $3^{9/4}$ rather that $3^{3/2}$?  And why can't you just put  $3^{9/4}$ in a calculator to see it's between $11$ and $12$?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, by doing this we can check the numbers and see that it works? This was just an example. Is there another way which helps to see the result without the need for calculations done by a calculator. For example, what is the desired maximum value is 3^(23/2)? It would not be easy to calculate.